# Not able to change Authentication in spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am creating one Spark-Cassandra App (Spark 1.6.0 & spark-cassandra-connector 1.6.0-M1), in which i am asking multiple users to enter their Cassandra properties like Host, Username, Password, Keyspace, Table and others.

To change the above properties dynamically and create dataframe from Cassandra table, I Googled and found out some information

http://www.russellspitzer.com/2016/02/16/Multiple-Clusters-SparkSql-Cassandra/

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#setting-cluster-and-keyspace-level-options

```
val csc = new CassandraSQLContext(SparkConnection._sc)

csc.setConf(s"${cluster}/spark.cassandra.connection.host", host)
csc.setConf(s"${cluster}/spark.cassandra.connection.port", port)
csc.setConf(s"${cluster}/spark.cassandra.auth.username", username)
csc.setConf(s"${cluster}/spark.cassandra.auth.password", password)

csc.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                  .options(Map("cluster" -> cluster, "keyspace" -> keySpace, "table" -> table))
                  .load()
```

I tried with mention properties, Clusters those doesn't require authentication is connecting successfully but when i try to connect with secure cluster using username & password properties, i am getting some error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {192.168.1.17}:9042
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:162)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraRDDPartitioner$.getTokenFactory(CassandraRDDPartitioner.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
    at com.bdbizviz.pa.spark.util.ServiceUtil$.readData(ServiceUtil.scala:97)
    at com.bdbizviz.pa.spark.services.SparkServices$$anon$1.run(SparkServices.scala:114)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /192.168.1.17:9042: Host /192.168.1.17:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AuthProvider$1.newAuthenticator(AuthProvider.java:40)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$5.apply(Connection.java:250)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$5.apply(Connection.java:234)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:861)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Future.onSet(Connection.java:1174)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1005)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:928)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:831)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:254)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The configuration keys need to include the keyspace also. They should look something like:

```
${cluster}:${keyspace}/spark.cassandra.connection.host
```

etc.

If you look at your second link that is what the `setCassandraConf` function translates things into.